# Insert widget in CMS page using the id of widget?

Tags: magento2, cms, widget

It's able to insert a widget in any CMS page using **insert widget** button. How can we insert an already created widget using its id in CMS page. I googled a lot...but not able to find this one.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: I did not get solution as I expected, so just copied same widget in other page also.

Comment: ok, thanks for answering :) so I guess the only way to make this work is the widget's own layout update functionality